# Run Gulp Task in Codekit Hook

Tags: gulp, codekit

I'm trying to run a Gulp task as a Codekit Hook after compiling JS files.

I've created a new Hook and put in the following command:

```
cd /path/to/my/web/project/
gulp default
```

I just want to run a gulp task everytime Codekit has compiled my JS files. But nothing happens. What i'm doing wrong?

If i run that task in the terminal, everything is fine.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

My solution was to make a Shell Script and link directly to it in the Codekit Hook:

E.g.:

```
./rungulptasks.sh
```

Inside the "rungulptasks.sh" file I put a direct link to the local gulp bin:

```
node_modules/.bin/gulp
```

Now it works. Solved.

P.S Don't forget to make the script executable.

Comment: I need to do exactly the same..can you explain this a bit better? Like posting an example code for example...thanks a lot

Comment: You can also add this as a Build step by adding a new "Run Script" step (shell script) and adding the node_modules/.bin/gulp line there.